# Python - Instaloader ProfileNotExistsException

Tags: python

I am new to Instaloader and I am running into a problem when trying to pull in Bio information. We have scraped Google for a list of Instagram handles for our accounts, unfortunately the data isn't perfect and some of the handles we have pulled in are no longer active(User has changed profile handle or deleted account). This causes the `ProfileNotExistsException` error to come up and stops pulling in the information for all subsequent accounts.

Is there a way to ignore this and continue pulling in the rest of the bios while just leaving this one blank?

Here is the code that is throwing me the error. handles is the list of handles we have.

```
bios = [] 
for element in handles: 
    if element == '': bios.append('NULL') 
    else:
    bios.append(instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, element).biography)
```

I have tried using the workaround found in this forum(can't find the post) but it is not working for me. No errors, just not solving the issue. The code they suggested was:

```
def _obtain_metadata(self): 
    try: 
        if self._rhx_gis == None: 
            metadata = self._context.get_json('{}/'.format(self.username), params={}) 
        self._node = metadata['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user'] 
        self._rhx_gis = metadata['rhx_gis'] 
        metadata = self._context.get_json('{}/'.format(self.username), params={}) 
        self._node = metadata['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user'] 
except (QueryReturnedNotFoundException, KeyError) as err: 
    raise ProfileNotExistsException('Profile {} does not exist.'.format(self.username)) from err
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im also having this kind of problem, but this is raised after HTTP to many requests.
So, reason for your error can be to many requests

Comment: Did you find a solution ?